# ddrescue -- which files are in error locations?

Tags: ext4, dd

I had a HDD crash and had to use ddrescue to restore it. It took a month, but it finally finished today. However, there were three errors that it could not read. Is there a way to find out which files were there (if any)? The filesystem is ext4.

Answer (score 3):

[`ddrutility`](https://sourceforge.net/p/ddrutility/wiki/Home/) was created for just this purpose.

I successfully got it to list affected NTFS files given a `ddrescue` mapfile in under 20 seconds.

It writes its log file in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the bad blocks in those files by filling the bad sectors with some string (check out http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Fill-mode).  Then you can grep through all files for that string.

I haven't tried this script myself, but you could try using a script like http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860559 which operates on a similar principle to find affected files.